# How can i change uialertcontroller's textfield content?

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, uialertcontroller

I am using UIAlertController to getting name variable like this ;

[image]

In android my friends can put variables in Alert Controller when alert controller pops up comes like this;

[image]

they can put variables in text field and start with it.

But I couldn't, I tried to

alertController.textFields?.first?.text = myNameVariable

but it didn't work.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Update Name", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Update", style: .default) { (_) in
                if let txtField = alertController.textFields?.first, let text = txtField.text {
                    // operations
                    alertController.textFields?.first?.text = "Variable that i already have" // I want to change textfield content
                    print("Text==>" + text)
                }
            }
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in }
            alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
                textField.placeholder = "name"
            }
            alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
```

sorry for uploading IBB instead of Imgur, in my country Imgur is blocked :/

Comment: Where did you call `alertController.textFields?.first?.text = myNameVariable`? And what precisely does "it didn't work" mean? It crashed? It did nothing? It did something else unexpected?

Comment: @Alexander it wasnt crashed but nothing happened,

i call it before let confirmAction

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice it at first. At that point, you haven't created the textfield yet, so it obviously won't exist in the `textFields` array. But why are you even trying to access it in such a strange way, when you already have such easy and convenient access to it, in the form of the `textField` parameter. You already even do `textField.placeholder = "name"`. Why not set the `text` there in the exact same way?

Comment: @Alexander thank you for your kindly answer, for swift i am very newbie in this stage and i am trying to learn. it worked fine thank you ^^

Comment: @Alexander But the text field is being created first. The code inside the "Update" button handler is called when the alert is dismissed. By the time that code would be called, the call to `addTextField` was made already. Having said that, there is no point to updating a text field in a button handler. At that point you should only be reading whatever value was entered by the user.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you for explaining, after first answer i moved it to top, thank you too also ^^

Comment: @rmaddy Good point. I totally overlooked how these closures are being used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add the text field before you would access it

here is an example

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Update Name", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

alertController.addTextField { textField in
    textField.text = "Text goes here 1"
    textField.placeholder = "placeholder"
    textField.tag = 0
}

alertController.addTextField { textField in
    textField.text = "Text goes here 2"
    textField.tag = 1
}

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { _ in

    let firstTextField = alertController.textFields?.first
    let secondTextField = alertController.textFields?.last


    print(firstTextField?.text, secondTextField?.text)
}))
```

**Edit**

Thanks to @rmaddy

The problem with question's code is that it's trying to set the text field's text after the alert has been dismissed. This makes little sense. Once a user taps one of the alert buttons, the user has already entered text into the text field. The code should be trying to read the user's entered text from the text field, not trying to update the text field's text.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly answer, i understand what is wrong hope you have a great day ^^

Comment: While this answer is correct, it doesn't really explain what was wrong. The problem with the OP's code is that they are trying to set the text field's text after the alert has been dismissed. This makes little sense. Once a user taps one of the alert buttons, the user has already entered text into the text field. The OP's code should be trying to read the user's entered text from the text field, not trying to update the text field's text.

Comment: You misunderstand my comment. The OP was already adding the text field before trying to access it. Simply moving the call to `addTextField` doesn't change anything. The OP's error had nothing to do with the order of their code. The problem was trying to set the text field in the button handler. That's too late. The alert is already gone by then. The only thing you should do in a button handler is *read* the text, not try to *write* it. The only change in your answer that is relevant is that you update in the text field in the call to `addTextField` instead of the button handler.

Comment: @rmaddy it's fine I appreciate your comment and your feedback